# cannot call the second view from my template in django

Tags: django

I am creating a web app. In this one button is for getting the user data and another button is for adding a new user. I have successfully added the button which pressed shows the user but the second button is not working.

this is my html

```
{% extends "edit_parameter.html" %}


{%block title %}  <title>User Management</title> {% endblock %}

{%block css %}
table.table_font{

font-size:10%;

}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>
    <center>User Management Menu</center>
</h1>

<form method="POST" action="{% url 'get_user_data' %}" >
    {% csrf_token %}

    <table BORDER=0 style="float:left; margin-top:1px; margin-left:30px;">

        <tr>
            <td> &nbsp;<label for="user_id">User ID:</label></td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="user_id" name="user_id" type="text" value="{{ user_id }}"><br></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> &nbsp;<label for="user_name">User Name:</label></td>
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="user_name" name="user_name" type="text" value="{{ user_name }}"><br></td>
        </tr>




    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" >Get user data</button>
<a href="success" class="btn btn-dark" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Menu</a>
                <button   class="btn btn-danger"  onclick="location.href={% url 'add_new_user' %}">add_new_user</button>



</form>
```

this is my views.py

```
def get_user_data(req):
#somecodehere
return render('user.html')



def add_new_user(req):
#somecodehere
return render('user.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to send the user_id and user_name to the add_new_user, or not...?
this will not:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="location.href={% url 'add_new_user' %}">add_new_user</button>
```

(notice the type="button" there)

if you want to send them, I'd change the action and submit the form, like:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="this.form.action='{% url 'add_new_user' %}';this.form.submit();">add_new_user</button>
```